# Login with Facebook Integration With Keycloak using custom login

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, keycloak

I am trying to integrate the Keycloak with Facebook social plugin. I had gone through the examples and documentation. This works fine if I use the Keycloak hosted Login Page.

What I need is that we want to host our own login page and use the Keycloak APIs to register the user and login. I mean, I want to host our Sign Up/Login Page.

When the user clicks on the Login with Facebook, we want to redirect the user to FB and get the approval and collect the details, create the user details that we need for our application. Then register the user on the Keycloak.

I don’t see any documentation for this. I would be really grateful if you can shed some light on this and point to the documentation that would help me in achieving this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any solution Maddy...Looking for the same..How you managed?

Comment: Have you found any solution mate?

Answer (score -1):

For that I think you have to register your application with facebook using a valid facebook user account to connect with facebook API services.

Refer : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers/